# CSS transition have a black background at the beginning, why?

Tags: html, css

I have a transition on the heart, but for some reason, at the beginning of the animation, it turns black first before doing the desired gradient.

Here is the code:

```css
.heart {
     font-size: 2.5rem;
     padding-right: 2rem;
     }

.heart:hover::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f004";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#9356DC, #FF79DA);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  transition: 5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
        />
<span class="fa-regular fa-heart heart"></span>
```

I would like to understand where this black background comes from at the beginning of the transition.

I tried different things, like adding a `background-color` property. But it doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks a lot in advance

Edit : I changed the duration of the transition from .9s to 5s to make it clear what I mean.
Putting color on the element does not solve the problem, the heart must have a black outline when the cursor is not on it.

Comment: it's the default black color. update `color` to change it

Comment: If I try to put a color on the normal element without over, it becomes invisible as long as the cursor does not pass over it, because it blends into the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, correct? Similar to a like button on Instagram. I've achieved this by creating a second pseudo-element `::after` with the same styling as the `before` on hover. Now on hover I change the opacity of the `before` to 0 and the `after` to 1, with a transition, this fades over to each other nicely. It is required to give the `.heart` element position relative so the `after` can be positioned directly over the `before`

```css
.heart {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.heart::before {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.heart::after {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  content: "\f004";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#9356DC, #FF79DA)!important;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}

.heart:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.heart:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" />

<span class="fa-regular fa-heart heart"></span>
```

Comment: Yes but with progressive transition.

Comment: thanks. Because i have add  "transition: .9s ease-in-out;" on your code, and it's same to my share code, thank you.

Comment: Check this one out, is this your desired result?

Comment: No sorry. It's same to me: because, before the gradient, the heart is full of black for a few milliseconds. 
But thanks for trying.
I'll have to find another way to do it.

Comment: Wait! I just found something out, its a little messy but it works perfectly. You create an after with the color and desired result for the hover, then change opacity from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 with a transition value, making it fade to the filled gradient heart! Check the snippet

Comment: But, for some reason, it doesn't work that way when integrated into my code, strange. But I mark it as validated, thanks! I'll try to solve the reason why it doesn't work for me.
Thanks again.

Edit : Oh no, it's ok, I just forgot to start the sass compilation when I started my PC. Very Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

```css
.heart {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  /* ADD These line of code */
  background: linear-gradient(#9356DC, #FF79DA);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.heart:hover::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f004";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#9356DC, #FF79DA);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  transition: 0.9s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" />

<span class="fa-regular fa-heart heart"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the heart without over is not black and is a problem in my case.

Comment: okay, i have change de linear-gradient on element without :hover by (#fff, #fff), but it's not progressive